# Trouble with "inputstream" when creating mobile app that downloads weather information (with AsyncTask)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to make a mobile app that downloads info from the openweathermap.org apis.  For example, if you feed that app this link: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Boston,us&appid=fed33a8f8fd54814d7cbe8515a5c25d7 you will get the information about the weather in Boston, MA.  My code seems to work up to the point where I have to convert the input stream to a string variable.  When I do that, I get garbage.  Is there a particular way to do this seemingly simple task in a proper way?  Here is my code so far...

```
      private class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        try {
            return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);
        if(result!=null) test.setText(result);
        else{
            Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "returned result is null");}
    }
}

private String downloadUrl(String myurl) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = null;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(myurl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000 /* milliseconds */);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        // Starts the query
        conn.connect();
        int response = conn.getResponseCode();
        Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "The response is: " + response);
        is = conn.getInputStream();
        String text = getStringFromInputStream(is);
        //JSONObject json = new JSONObject(text);

        //try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())) {
        //text = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        //}

        //Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        return text;
    }catch(Exception e) {
        Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, e.toString());
    }finally {
        if (is != null) {
            is.close();
        }
    }

    return null;
}


private static String getStringFromInputStream(InputStream is) {

    BufferedReader br = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();

}
```

Comment: whats the problem you are facing? aren't you getting the string from inputstream properly??

Comment: Please post garbage result sample in your question.

Comment: This download is designed to return a string such as: {"coord":{"lon":-71.06,"lat":42.36},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken...etc, but when I convert the inputstream to a String using my current method of doing so, I get a garbage result such as ������JFIF����d��d��������C��.

Comment: This result is not a string, it is a JSONObject try printing the sb.toString() in a Log and if you get the same result let me know

Comment: the "JFIF" in your string looks like you are receiving a jpg image and not a string although your test-url returns a json string when called from a browser. Have you tried if calling `getStringFromInputStream()` from the gui thread (without async) produce the same result to find out if the problem is related to async or not?

Comment: Yeah, I realized I made a silly error when feeding a url to this downloader/parser and I regret even asking the question in the first place.  Sorry...and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [library](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) . Is An asynchronous callback-based Http client for Android built on top of Apache’s HttpClient libraries.